# AVL Tree balance function cannot set new height after balancing

Tags: c++

I have been trying to implement an AVL tree in C++, and I believe that I have programmed everything correctly except for one line. The structure of the program is as follows.

```
    struct AvlNode
{
    int key;
    int height;
    AvlNode *left;
    AvlNode *right;
    AvlNode(int key1, int height1 = 0, AvlNode *left1 = NULL, AvlNode *right1 = NULL)
    {
        key = key1;
        height = height1;
        left = left1;
        right = right1;
    }
};

class AvlTree
{
private:
    AvlNode * root;
    void destroySubTree(AvlNode * v);//destroy a subtree rooted at v
    void displayPreOrder(AvlNode *);//pre-order traversal
    void displayInOrder(AvlNode *);//in-order traversal
    void displayPostOrder(AvlNode *);//post-order traversal
    void remove(AvlNode * &, int);//remove
    void insert(AvlNode * &, int);//insert
    void balance(AvlNode * &); //make the tree balanced after each insert/remove
    void rightRotate(AvlNode * &);//right rotation
    void leftRotate(AvlNode * &);//left rotation
    void doubleLeftRightRotate(AvlNode * &);//left right double rotation
    void doubleRightLeftRotate(AvlNode * &);//right left double rotation

public:
    AvlTree() { root = NULL; }
    ~AvlTree() { destroySubTree(root); }
    AvlNode * search(int);
    void displayPreOrder() { displayPreOrder(root); }
    void displayInOrder() { displayInOrder(root); }
    void displayPostOrder() { displayPostOrder(root); }
    void insert(int x) { insert(root, x); }//insert a new key x
    void remove(int x) { remove(root, x); }//remove a key x
    int getHeight(AvlNode * v);//return the height of node v
    int getTreeHeight() { return getHeight(root); }//return the height of the tree
    int getRoot() { return root->key; }//return the root
    int max(int x, int y);
};
```

So the issue I am having arises in the balance method which is as follows:

```
void AvlTree::balance(AvlNode * & v)
{
    if (v == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    if ((getHeight(v->left) - getHeight(v->right)) > 1)
    {
        if (getHeight(v->left->left) >= getHeight(v->left->right))
            rightRotate(v);
        else
            doubleLeftRightRotate(v);
    }
    if ((getHeight(v->right) - getHeight(v->left)) > 1)
    {
        if (getHeight(v->right->left) >= getHeight(v->right->right))
            doubleRightLeftRotate(v);
        else
            leftRotate(v);
    }
    v->height = 1 + max(getHeight(v->left), getHeight(v->right));
}
```

The final line of the method is where the compiler freaks out on me. When I run the program visual studio says source.exe has stopped working. Is that because I can't directly assign the height of the node as I attempted? If not, what could be a potential fix to this problem here? I have tried many different ways of setting the height of the node after balancing, but it simply will not allow it. Thanks for the help in advance!

When I run the program in the debugger it stops at the first line of the rightRotate method: which is as follows:

```
void AvlTree::rightRotate(AvlNode * & k2)
{
    AvlNode * k1 = k2->left;
    k2->left = k1->right;
    k1->right = k2;
    k2->height = 1 + max(getHeight(k2->left), getHeight(k2->right));
    k1->height = 1 + max(getHeight(k1->left), k2->height);
    k2 = k1;
}
```

Comment: And if you run in a debugger, does it stop where you think the crash happens, or somewhere else?

Comment: it stops at the first line of the rightRotate method, I added the code for said method in the main question above. I'm starting to second guess how well written my code is in the other functions of the program . . .

Comment: That seems to indicate that your pointers are not what you expect them to be. As you rearrange the tree you remember to set the leaves `left` and `right` pointer to `NULL` as needed? The same when you delete nodes, you set the parent nodes left or right pointer to `NULL`? And why don't you check for `right` and `left` pointers not being `NULL` before dereferencing them?

Comment: To debug this issue further, run your program in the debugger and *step* through the code line by line. Use a small tree to minimize the calls and recursions.